# configring git bash on windows to run phpunit

Tags: phpunit, git-bash

I'm using a Win7x64 PC in order to write my php code. I'm still on the learning phase of using PHPUnit. I'm using phpunit from bash command line. I'll like to have the colors in git bash when I run my tests.

I got bash when I installed git for windows. On git commands, I get the coloring.

ps: using `phpunit --colors` doesn't change anything